# how to connect javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am really new to web development. i want to calculate travel distance between two airports.
if via is filled then the city will be calculated into the total distance.
if via is not filled, i could still calculate the non-stop air travel distance, but how can i pass the value to php file in javascript. 
i think my code has problem in javascript part 
Also, is this list($co2, $miles) json ? can i parse this list in javascript ?

this is html part:

```
<div>
    From
    <div class="textinput">
        <input type="text" id="dept" name="departure" placeholder="City name or aiport code" >
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    To
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="dest" placeholder="City name or airport code" >
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Via
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="via" value="0" placeholder="City name or airport code" >
    </div>
</div>
```

this is javascript part

```
var $dept = $("#dept");
var $dest = $("#dest");
var $via = $("#via");
$("#aircalc").on('click', function() {
    if($("#airradio1").is(':checked')) {
        $("#airanswer").val("");
        $.post('airtravel1.php',{dept: $dept.val(), dest: $dest.val(), via: $via.val()},         function(data) {
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var a = response.co2;
                var mile = (response.miles).toFixed(4);
                var numpass = $("#numpass").val();
                var flightclass = $("#flightclass").val();
                var trip = $("input[name='trip']:checked").val();
                var total = (a * trip * flightclass * numpass).toFixed(2);
                var sum = "<div>Trip from " + $dept.val() + " to " + $dest.val() + ", you traveled " + mile + "miles</div>";
                $("#airanswer").text(total);
                $("#airresult").on('click',function(){
                $("#results").append(sum);
            });
        });
    } else {
        myairFunction2();
    }
});
```

php part:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dept'], $_POST['dest'])) {
    $dept=$_POST['dept'];
    $dest=$_POST['dest'];
}
mysql_connect("localhost","ccc","aaa") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ccc") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['via'])) {
    $via=$_POST['via'];
    list($co2, $miles) = indirect($dept, $dest, $via);
} else {
    list($co2, $miles) = direct($dept, $dest);
}
function direct($dept, $dest) {
    $strSQL1 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$dept'";
    $rs1 = mysql_query($strSQL1);
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1);
    $lat1= $row1['lat'];
    $long1= $row1['longi'];
    $strSQL2 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$dest'";
    $rs2 = mysql_query($strSQL2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    $lat2= $row2['lat'];
    $long2= $row2['longi'];
    $earthradius = 6366.707;
    $km_to_miles = 1/1.609344;
    $dlat = ($lat2-$lat1) * (M_PI / 180);
    $dlon = ($long2-$long1) * (M_PI / 180);
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + sin($dlon / 2) * sin($dlon / 2) * cos($lat1 * (M_PI / 180)) * cos($lat2 * (M_PI / 180));
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
    $d = $c * $earthradius;
    $miles = $d * $km_to_miles;
    $co2 = (($miles / 41.986) * 20.88 * 1.9) / 2204.6;
    return [$co2, $miles];
}
function indirect($dept, $dest, $via) {
    $strSQL1 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$dept'";
    $rs1 = mysql_query($strSQL1);
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1);
    $lat1= $row1['lat'];
    $long1= $row1['longi'];
    $strSQL2 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$dest'";
    $rs2 = mysql_query($strSQL2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    $lat2= $row2['lat'];
    $long2= $row2['longi'];
    $strSQL3 = "SELECT display, lat, longi FROM airport WHERE display = '$via'";
    $rs3 = mysql_query($strSQL3);
    $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3);
    $lat3= $row3['lat'];
    $long3= $row3['longi'];
    $earthradius = 6366.707;
    $km_to_miles = 1/1.609344;
    $dlat1 = ($lat3-$lat1) * (M_PI / 180);
    $dlon1 = ($long3-$long1) * (M_PI / 180);
    $a1 = sin($dlat1 / 2) * sin($dlat1 / 2) + sin($dlon1 / 2) * sin($dlon1 / 2) * cos($lat1 * (M_PI / 180)) * cos($lat3 * (M_PI / 180));
    $c1 = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a1), sqrt(1-$a1));
    $d1 = $c1 * $earthradius;
    $miles1 = $d1 * $km_to_miles;
    $dlat2 = ($lat3-$lat2) * (M_PI / 180);
    $dlon2 = ($long3-$long2) * (M_PI / 180);
    $a2 = sin($dlat2 / 2) * sin($dlat2 / 2) + sin($dlon2 / 2) * sin($dlon2 / 2) * cos($lat2 * (M_PI / 180)) * cos($lat3 * (M_PI / 180));
    $c2 = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a2), sqrt(1-$a2));
    $d2 = $c2 * $earthradius;
    $miles2 = $d2 * $km_to_miles;
    $miles = $miles1 + $miles2;
    $co2 = (($miles / 41.986) * 20.88 * 1.9) / 2204.6;
    return [$co2, $miles];
}
?>
```

Comment: **mysql_*** is **deprecated** use PDO or MySQLi!

Comment: What response you get after `$.post` complete? did you go in success portion or else?

Comment: if you didn't get success then use like this so you will know where did you go after php script complete  `$.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});`

Answer (score -1):

Change your Javascript code like this

```
var data={dept: $dept.val(), dest: $dest.val(), via: $via.val()}; 
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'airtravel1.php',data:data,success:function(data)
{
//your call back
  console.log(data)
}});
```

Comment: does it work to the situation when via is not filled?